# Design elements for inline asm in concurrent usage

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, concurrency

I can't find a neat explanation about how I'm supposed to write a piece of inline asm, and what are the problem that can possibly arise from a concurrent use of a `foo` function that contains `asm` code in it.

The problem that I see is that in `asm` the registers are uniquely named, and so 1 name is strictly tied to a really precise portion of your cpu, and that's a big problem if you are writing 1 piece of code that is supposed to run concurrently because you can't simply extra registers with the same name.

The other problem is that `asm` doesn't really uses a calling convention, you simply call registers and/or values, and sometimes calling a register implies a *silent* action on another register that doesn't even shows up explicitly in your code; so I can't even expect that my C/C++ function `foo` will be packed and sealed inside its own stack if it contains `asm` code .

Now with what `gcc` calls [`extended asm`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) I can basically declare where the input and the output goes, so each function can use its own parameters *"as registers"* , and the pattern is the following

```
   asm ( assembler template 
       : output               
       : input               
       : registers 
       );
```

Assuming that my main target for now are mathematical operations, and my function is only supposed to give a certain functionality and perform some computation ( no internal lock ), is extended asm good for concurrency ? How I should design a piece of asm that is supposed to be used by a concurrent application ?

For now I'm using `gcc`, but I would like a generic answer about the general `asm` design that I'm supposed to give to this kind of code snippets.

Comment: "1 name is strictly tied to a really precise portion of your cpu, and that's a big problem if you are writing 1 piece of code that is supposed to run concurrently because you can't simply extra registers with the same name." - well, this is just plainly wrong. Please, do make sure you understand what threading is before writing multithreaded code.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Could you explain it ? if I write `%eax` in my `asm` code I don't think I can possibly get something other than what the `eax` register is or contains ...

Comment: Each thread has its own set of registers. You don't have to share them. Each thread also has its own stack, you don't share that either. All the other memory you share.

Comment: @Fozi are you assuming the use of a `sequentially consistent` memory order ? Like in C++11 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/memory_order/ by default ?

Comment: [Mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative))

Comment: @Fozi so, in the end I can write inline asm for concurrent usage just like I did for single-threaded applications ?

Comment: @user2485710 That's right, same rules apply. Same rules apply for sharing between threads as well, but memory ordering is for the compiler. You are the compiler now.

Comment: @user2485710 : That's what I was trying to tell you with my answer, along with an explanation. Oh well.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I wasn't trying to ignore your question, I always try to ask the same thing in different ways or try to write down the same explanation in different form; the main point about this is that it's not really clear to me what memory order is in practice and how this can influence my `asm` code. I heard that some particular ordering are really hard to get right in real world applications and I can't even find articles about asm ( or low level instructions ) and different memory order operations. Anyway now the thing is a little bit more clear, the real problem is that often times

Comment: the assembly language it's not even mentioned in C and C++ texts/books/articles, and this doesn't really help to understand how things really work.

Comment: The real problem is that you're probably wondering about it when you don't really need to. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what threading actually is. Let's consider a single-processor system first. The threads don't **actually** run concurrently, since there is only one unit that can successfully decode and execute them. Your operating system is only creating the illusion of running multiple threads (and processes, too) by employing scheduling inside of it : every thread, or process, is allocated a certain amount of time it gets to execute on the processor.

This is why, when threads are executed, they don't overwrite each other's registers. When a currently executed thread or process is switched, the operating system asks the processor to perform something that's called a context switch. In a nutshell, the processor saves its state when it was executing the previous task/thread/process into some memory area, which is controlled by the OS. The new task/thread/process has its context restored from the previously stored state and continues its execution. When this task/thread/process' time slice on the CPU is up, the scheduler decides which task/thread/process to resume next. The time slice is usually very small, which is why you're given the illusion of multiple streams of code running at the same time. Keep in mind that this is a very, **very** simplified description : refer to CPU manuals or books on operating systems for more detail.

The situation is analogous on multi-processor systems : only with the exception that, then, there is more than one unit that can execute the instructions. This is also true for multi-core processors : every one of the cores has its own set of registers. The basic stuff stays the same - the scheduler in your OS decides whether the code being executed is **actually** executed at the same time by multiple cores in one processor.

Thus, your concerns in this case are not valid. However, they were raised for very valid reasons. Remember that the only things that threads share is the main memory : each thread has its own registers, and its own stack.

Let me come back to the actual question about gcc's extended inline assembly. The compiler itself cannot work out which registers are modified by the assembly you wrote. That's why you need to specify it. However, it is very rare that an instruction modifies a register without you being able to control it, and it happens only with a small number of instructions - assuming that we're talking about x86. Moreover, gcc can work out the destination/source operands by itself when you want to refer to a C/C++ variable from inside the assembly. In fact, this is the preferred method, since it leaves the compiler much more room for optimization.

Consider this piece of code :

```
unsigned int get_cr0(void)
{
    unsigned int rc;
    __asm__ (
        "movl %%cr0, %0\n"
        : "=r"(rc)
        :
        :
    );
    return rc;
}
```

This function's purpose is to return the contents of the control register `cr0`. This is a privileged instruction, so the program will not work when you run it in user mode, but this is not important right now. See how I put `%0` in the instruction, and then specified `"=r"(rc)` in the output list. This means that `%0` will be automagically aliased by the compiler to your `rc` variable. You can do this for every variable you specify on the input/output list. They are numbered starting from zero, as you can see.

I can't really remember the instructions which used registers that were not encoded as operands, so I can't give you an example right now. In this case, you would need to put them on the clobber list (the last one). I'm pretty sure you can refer to [this](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3) for more information.

I also can't answer anything regarding "general `asm` design", since this is a non-standard extension and thus varies between compilers. The 64-bit Visual Studio compilers don't support it at all, for example.

Comment: what about cpus with Hyper Threading ? In that case 1 core runs 2 logical threads. What prevents a cpu manifacturer to create a CPU with a concurrent use of the registers anyway ? A real explanation is that the so called "context switch" it's about making a "backup" of the registers when moving between threads.

Comment: CPUs with Hyper Threading are seen as 2 logical cores, because each core maintains its own "architectural state", as defined by Intel in their manuals. This includes the register states. "Concurrent" registers are a no-no because they would need locking, and registers are meant to be the fastest storage possible. That doesn't mean it's not possible to implement : I'm just not aware of any architectures that would actually do it.

Comment: what we are saying here it's valid for ARM and MIPS too ?

Comment: No, only x86. I'm not familiar enough with any other architectures (regarding the "concurrent registers" - all the other stuff stays the same).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244104/design-elements-for-inline-asm-in-concurrent-usage#comment32043379_21244104